# Auto-executed anonymous functions shortcut in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, delegates, anonymous-function

I have this code :

(simple enum which has values for a,b,c ...[0,1,2] , and i want to show for each looped number  - its corrosponding `enum` in a final list).

```
public enum ENM
{
   a,b,c
}


void Main()
{

var e = Enumerable.Range(0,3).Select(myCounter=>new {

          final=((Func<int,ENM>)delegate (int i)
                                    {
                                         return (ENM)i;
                                    })(myCounter)

}).ToList();
```

this is fine and working.

Is there any solution without writing `delegate(int i) {...}`?

*p.s. of course I can just write `(ENM)i` but the question is for learning
 how to write ( in different ways ) the auto-executed methods.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
Enumerable.Range(0,3).Select(c=>(ENM)c).ToList()
```

or am I missing some reason for the over complexity?

```
var e = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(myCounter => new
{
    final = ((Func<int, ENM>)(
        i=>{ 
            return (ENM)i;
            /* More code could be here */
        }))(myCounter)
}).ToList();
```

is about as tight as you will get if you want the same mess :)

Comment: yeah you missing the last sentence :-)

Comment: The point is that ( i=>(ENM)i ) is not an anonymous function until you cast it to Func<int, ENM> so you can't avoid the cast if you want to execute the function immediately

Comment: @RoyiNamir Why the edit? It was correct code. Nobody would write a single line anonymous function like you have?

Comment: it is a part to emphasize that you can write more code in it....I just wanted it to be emphasized. ( maybe it should show `...`)... you didnt get the point of my question.

Comment: Ok. I've made it clearer otherwise somebody else will come along and edit the code back to the single line expression style.

Comment: Someonelse could come and downvote  by saying "you dont need `{}` " lol hhhh

Comment: Really the question is just about casting lambda's to delegates and nothing to do with how much code is in the delegate or casting of enumerables. Lambdas are not the same as delegates. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
var e = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ENM)).Select((e, i) => new { final = e, index = i }).ToList();
```

OR

```
var EnumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ENM));
var EnumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ENM)).Cast<ENM>().Select(e => (int)e);
var result = EnumNames.Zip(EnumValues, (n, v) => new { final = n, index = v });
```

Comment: you missing the last sentence

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific method in `System.Enum` for doing exactly this:

```
var arr = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ENM));
```

To get it into a `List<ENM>`:

```
var lst = arr.Cast<ENM>().ToList();
```

Comment: you missing the last sentence

Comment: @RoyiNamir What am I missing?